# Start programs in full-screen (Python)

Tags: python, linux

I tried to open a file, the filename is 1.txt. I tried to open it with webbrowser.open("1.txt") or os.startfile("1.txt") which worked perfectly fine, but I couldn't find any information about how to start programs or anything with Python in full screen. I'm using Linux and Python 3.6.

Any ideas how to perform something like that?

Comment: Btw im not using Pygame or any other thing just normal Python command prompt.

Comment: I dont think that's possible. The specified commands start the default application from the operating systen. It is not clear that this application opens a window, since you can change this application to anything you want.

Comment: You're probably looking for the `subprocess` module. But the "fullscreen" part is completely application dependent, there's no reliable way to start any application in "fullscreen" mode.

Comment: Anyway, `os.startfile` is documented as Windows only. Are you sure you used it on Linux?

Comment: yes im am sure.. i imported a library that i can use most of the windows sided python commands. kinda working but still do you have any idea how to perform something like that to start a program maximized or maybe call a command from linux to do that anything like that?

Answer (score -1):

There are more answers to that question than there are GUI toolkits, and there are plenty of toolkits.

I think the first thing you need to do is decide on a GUI toolkit. Research it depending on your necessities (python version, OS support, etc). Once you settle on one, find out how to make a fullscreen app with that. If you can't, ask again.

Good luck.

Comment: The point is i want to start a third party program (in that case the editor) in full screen i dont want to make a gui program or anything like that.

Comment: Oh, well, in that case try to find if whatever editor you are using accepts runtime parameters, and whether is has a parameter to execute into fullscreen. (There must be OS hooks to manipulate such things, but I don't know therm )

Comment: its kinda funny that i can do such thing on windows just with one argument but in python/linux its a more complicated process

Comment: Or any idea if i can use a system command to start the program maximized? with bash or shell script something like that?